# Why does Keras documentation examples for autonencoders use Conv2D instead of Conv2DTranspose

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, tf.keras, deconvolution

I have been following the Keras documentation to build up a CNN autoencoder 
https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html .

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras import backend as K

input_img = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))  # adapt this if using `channels_first` image data format

x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# at this point the representation is (4, 4, 8) i.e. 128-dimensional

x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

I have noticed that it uses Conv2D in its decoding layers instead of Conv2DTranspose. But some other articles explain CNN autoencoders using Conv2DTranspose as a replacement for Upsampling2D and Conv2D. I have seen several questions related to Conv2DTranspose itself. But I haven't found an answer to my question.

My question is can I use Conv2DTranspose instead of Upsampling2D and Conv2D layers. If so, why haven't the authors themselves (Keras documentation) have not used it? Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 1):

Transpose Convolutions often result in artifacts called `Checkerboard artifacts` - Small adjacent squares easily distinguishable from each other. These make it very easy for humans to recognize fake images from real ones.

You can read [this article](https://distill.pub/2016/deconv-checkerboard/) for more information.

In short, using `Resizing + Conv2D` instead of `Conv2dTranspose` minimizes these checkerboard artifacts.